# Не создается указатель для обращения к функции

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Раньше работал с ней таким способом:

```
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hRes = pService->ExecQuery((BSTR)"WQL",
(BSTR)"SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor",
WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY,
NULL,
&pEnumerator)
```

Теперь необходимо вызвать примерно так:

```
VOID(WINAPI* TrueSleep)(DWORD dwMilliseconds) = Sleep; //пример для функции Sleep()
```

---

Я делаю так, но получаю ошибку

```
 VOID(WINAPI* ExecQuery)(BSTR argument) = Sleep;
```

Comment: Ну? Вам же явно написано что не так, к тому же указатель на метод нужно делать не так...

Comment: @mik.ov подскажете как?

Comment: Касты к `(BSTR)` невалидные. Так что ваш код и раньше не работал.

Comment: @user7860670 я конвертировал отдельно к wide_char, убрал от сюда для читаемости кода

Comment: В вопрос стоит добавлять только настоящий код, представляющий собой [mcve], а не какие-то видоизмененные обрывки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Стиль си:

```
#define EXEC_QUERY_ID 20

typedef HRESULT(__stdcall *PFN_WbemServicesExecQuery)(IWbemServices * This,
                                                      const BSTR strQueryLanguage,
                                                      const BSTR strQuery,
                                                      long lFlags,
                                                      IWbemContext *pCtx,
                                                      IEnumWbemClassObject **ppEnum);


IWbemServices * pWbemServices;
PFN_WbemServicesExecQuery *vtbl_ptr =
                           (PFN_WbemServicesExecQuery*) *((char**) pWbemServices);

PFN_WbemServicesExecQuery pfn_ptr = vtbl_ptr[EXEC_QUERY_ID];

// call

pfn_ptr(pWbemServices, ...);
```

2. Стиль c++:

```
typedef HRESULT(__stdcall IWbemServices::*PFN_ExecQuery)(const BSTR strQueryLanguage,
                                                         const BSTR strQuery,
                                                         long lFlags,
                                                         IWbemContext *pCtx,
                                                         IEnumWbemClassObject **ppEnum);

PFN_ExecQuery pQuery = &IWbemServices::ExecQuery;

// call

(pWbemServices->*pQuery)(...);
```

Comment: Интересно за что минус?

Comment: Ошибочка при вызове стиль с++:  class "IWbemServices" не содержит члена "pQuery"

Comment: Исправил, скобки забыл