# Получить адрес виртуального метода

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Виртуальный метод, адрес которого нужно получить. Адрес нужен в HEX - формате.

```
IWbemServices : public IUnknown
{
public:    
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ExecQuery( 
        /* [in] */ __RPC__in const BSTR strQueryLanguage,
        /* [in] */ __RPC__in const BSTR strQuery,
        /* [in] */ long lFlags,
        /* [in] */ __RPC__in_opt IWbemContext *pCtx,
        /* [out] */ __RPC__deref_out_opt IEnumWbemClassObject **ppEnum) = 0;
};
```

Более глобально метод лежит в структуре. Структура в хидере подключаемой библиотеки.
Пробовал получить таким способом:

```
IWbemServices* pService = NULL;
pLocator->ConnectServer((BSTR)wc, NULL, NULL, NULL, WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT, NULL, NULL, &pService)
void* ptr = pService->ExecQuery;
```

Выдает ошибку:
Ошибка E0300 указатель на привязанную функцию можно использовать только для вызова функции

Comment: Похоже на дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1230674/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8 Даже ошибки с кастами к BSTR остались.

Comment: Я же вам уже давал ответ, разве нет? Если нужен именно адрес функции, то используйте стиль си. E.g. стиль с++ дает оффсет на адрес относительно объекта.

Comment: @mik.ov ЭТО НЕ ДУБЛИКАТ ВОПРОСА, читайте внимательнее, тот вопрос - тоже мой

Comment: @War_Never_Changes, Это дубликат, т.к. в моем ответе как раз содержится указатель на функцию (Где написано про стиль си)...

Comment: @mik.ov к сожалению, не работает ваш ответ

Comment: Ошибки? Или как не работает?

Comment: Ох уж этот WinAPI style...